# Last activity link for question within watched tags has a different color

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks, tag-watching

The 'last activity' link for questions within my watched tags is blue, instead of gray for all other questions:

[image]

I don't think it's intentional; gray on yellow looks OK as well (but I'm not an accessibility expert).